# Outer product of large vectors exceeds memory

Tags: python, numpy

I have three 1D vectors. Let's say T with 100k element array, f and df each with 200 element array:

```
T = [T0, T1, ..., T100k]
f = [f0, f1, ..., f200]
df = [df0, df1, ..., df200]
```

For each element array, I have to calculate a function such as the following:

```
P =  T*f + T**2 *df
```

My first instinct was to use the NumPy outer to find the function with each combination of **f** and **df**

```
P1 = np.outer(f,T)
P2 = np.outer(df,T**2)
P = np.add.outer(P1, P2)
```

However, in this case, I am facing the ram issue and receiving the following error:

> Unable to allocate 2.23 PiB for an array with shape (200, 100000, 200,
> 100000) and data type float64

Is there a good way that I can calculate this?

My attempt using for loops

```
n=100
f_range = 5e-7
df_range = 1.5e-15

fsrc = np.arange(f - n * f_range, f + n * f_range, f_range) #array of 200
dfsrc = np.arange(df - n * df_range, df + n * df_range, df_range) #array of 200

dfnus=pd.DataFrame(fsrc)
numf=dfnus.shape[0]

dfnudots=pd.DataFrame(dfsrc)
numfdot=dfnudots.shape[0]

test2D = np.zeros([numf,(numfdot)])

for indexf, f in enumerate(fsrc):
    
    for indexfd, fd in enumerate(dfsrc):
        
        a=make_phase(T,f,fd) #--> this is just a function that performs T*f + T**2 *df
        zlauf2d=z_n(a, n=1, norm=1) #---> And this is just another function that takes this 1D "a" and gives another 1D element array
        test2D[indexf, indexfd]=np.copy(zlauf2d) #---> I do this so I could make a contour plot at the end. It just copys the same thing to 2D
```

Now my test2D has the shape of (200,200). This is what I want, however the floor loop is taking ages and I want somehow reduce two for loop to at least one.

Comment: There are some packages which may be able to handle this if `np.einsum` doesn't work. I think `opt_einsum` can chunk the calculation. Without `opt_einsum`, perhaps do calculation in smaller chunks manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using broadcasting:

```
P1 = (f[:, np.newaxis] * T).sum(axis=-1)
P2 = (df[:, np.newaxis] * T**2).sum(axis=-1)
P = P1[:, np.newaxis] + P2
```

Alternatively, using outer:

```
P1 = (np.outer(f, T)).sum(axis=-1)
P2 = (np.outer(df, T**2)).sum(axis=-1)
P = P1[..., np.newaxis] + P2
```

This produces an array of shape `(f.size, df.size) == (200, 200)`.

---

Generally speaking, if the *final* output array size is very large, one can either:

1. Reduce the size of the datatypes. One way is to change the datatypes of the arrays used to calculate the final output via `P1.astype(np.float32)`. Alternatively, some operations allow one to pass in a `dtype=np.float32` as a parameter.
2. Chunk the computation and work with smaller subsections of the result.

---

Based on the most recent edit, compute an array `a` with shape `(200, 200, 100000)`. Then, take its element-wise norm along the last axis to produce an array `z` with shape `(200, 200)`.

```
a = (
    f[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * T
    + df[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis] * T**2
)

# L1 norm along last axis.
z = np.abs(a).sum(axis=-1)
```

This produces an array of shape `(f.size, df.size) == (200, 200)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But I am a bit confused.  Isn't your solution just adding the elements per row. which means
that you only consider  lets say f1 and df1 together, but never f2
and df1.
 This will restrict my sampling which I am trying to avoid and the same reason I tried to use np.outer.

Comment: Ah, so you want `P.shape == (f.size, T.size, df.size)`? With your existing code, you need to swap the arguments of `P2 = ...` and not perform a full outer product for `P = ...`. I've edited my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you very much and I apologize for not being so clear. I am a bit rookie on this. I want to produce an array of shape (f.size, df.size) == (200, 200) at the end. Also, how do I exactly convert my data to np.float32

Comment: `P1` and `P2` both have shape `(200, 1000)` in the code you posted. You can sum them along the 2nd (`1000`) dimension before computing the final outer product.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my question. I originally tried to do it with for loop. Does your solution do the same thing? I have tried but couldn't be sure.

Comment: I've added a section at the bottom that seems roughly equivalent to the new changes.